# Finding DOM Values using eq([i])

Tags: javascript

I have the below code to get all the "Names" given in an IE form,  one after the other using javascript. This script suppose to use the IE DOM explorer to get the value.

There would be one or more values that would match the query below at any given time. Therefore, I'll have to use a "For Loop" to get and assign the value to a variable one after the other. I would like to find the maximum number of occurrence to use in the For loop, by getting the value from `$('tr.background-light:last').text()`. This will contain a number and a name. I am stripping the number only by splitting it `cnt=cnt.split(".",1)` and assigning this to a variable.

Then using that as my maximum number to loop and trying to assign the value to an array. But it isn't running.

```
javascript:(function()
{
    ver item;
    var cnt=$('tr.background-light:last').text(); //getting the last background-light value which will contain the total number of Affected Client's 
    cnt=cnt.split(".",1);                         // Stripping just the number out from the above variable    

    for (var i =0; i <cnt.length; i++)
    {
        item= $("tr.background-light:eq("+i+")").text(); //looping through to get  each affected client info
        alert(item)
    };
})();
```

Comment: Comments use forward slashes, not back slashes.

Comment: Why is your code prefaced with `javascript:`? Where is this code in your page?

Comment: @Huangism Don't edit a question to alter the code beyond formatting. What if the OP's actual issue was that the comments were syntax errors?

Comment: @ScottMarcus oh right, yes sorry, I was thinking he put those in when posting but yea they could be part of the code

Comment: I can spot at least two errors: 1) `ver = item;` ? Shouldn't it be `var item;` ? 2) Your starting your comments with backslashes when they should be forward slashes. I suggest you fix those errors and come back here if it's still not working.

Comment: All corrected as indicated. The code still has some bugs. I believe it is something to do with the For Loop. Any idea please